# Relative velocity with moving reference frames

Tags: geometry, lie-groups, rotations, kinematics

Suppose we have two moving coordinate frames $F_1$ and $F_2$. We know their position $p_{F_1}^W, p_{F_2}^W \in \mathbb{R}^3 $ as well as the respective orientations $R_{F_1}^W, R_{F_2}^W \in SO\left(3\right)$. Furthermore we know both frames' translational velocities $v_{F_1}^W, v_{F_2}^W \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and angular velocities $\omega_{F_1}^W, \omega_{F_2}^W \in \mathbb{R}^3$. All these quantities are given with respect to common reference frame $W$.

However I want to express all these quantities with respect to frame $F_1$.

What I could come up with:

$R^{F_1}_{F_2} = {R_{F_1}^{W}}^T R_{F_2}^W $ (Orientation of frame $F_2$ w.r.t $F_1$)

$p_{F_2}^{F_1} = {R_{F_1}^{W}}^T\left(p_{F_2}^W- p_{F_1}^W\right)$ (Position of frame $F_2$ w.r.t $F_1$)

$\omega_{F_1}^{F_1} = {R_{F_1}^{W}}^T\omega^W_{F_1}$ (Body fixed angular velocity of $F_1$) (Not sure)

$v_{F_1}^{F_1} = {R_{F_1}^{W}}^T v^W_{F_1}$ (Body fixed translational velocity of $F_1$) (Not sure)

**Most importantly**: I want to know the quantity $\omega_{F_2}^{F_1}$ and  $v_{F_2}^{F_1}$ that is the angular and translational velocity of Frame $F_2$ with respect of (as measured from) Frame $F_1$.

Comment: I get the following: $\omega_{F_2}^{F_1} =\omega_{F_2}^{W}-\omega_{F_1}^{W}$ and $v_{F_2}^{F_1} =v_{F_2}^{W}-v_{F_1}^{W}-\omega_{F_1}^{W}\times(p_{F_2}^{W}-p_{F_1}^{W})$, with $\times$ representing the vector product.

Comment: @AndersBeta Thankyou! The first is somewhat irritating. Could you please elaborate on how you got to your conclusions?

Answer (score 1):

Let me elaborate. Let $\vec A$ be an arbitrary time dependent vector (I am using here full "physics" vector notation). The derivative of this vector with respect to time in the frames $W$, $F_1$, and $F_2$ are different, and related to each other by:

$$ \frac{d^{F_1}\vec A}{dt}= \frac{d^{W}\vec A}{dt}-\vec\omega_{F_1}^W\!\times\!\vec A,\tag{1}$$
$$ \frac{d^{F_2}\vec A}{dt}= \frac{d^{W}\vec A}{dt}-\vec\omega_{F_2}^W\!\times\!\vec A.$$

This two equations, by the way, define $\vec\omega_{F_1}^W$ and $\vec\omega_{F_2}^W$. Combining the two we get:

$$ \frac{d^{F_2}\vec A}{dt}= \frac{d^{F_1}\vec A}{dt}-(\vec\omega_{F_2}^W-\vec\omega_{F_1}^W)\!\times\!\vec A.$$

Because $\vec A$ is arbitrary, this shows that:

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]{\vec\omega_{F_2}^{F_1}=\vec\omega_{F_2}^W-\vec\omega_{F_1}^W }$$

To get the second equation, we can use the definitions of $\vec v_{F_1}^W$, $\vec v_{F_2}^W$ and $\vec v_{F_2}^{F_1}$:

$$\vec v_{F_1}^W = \frac{d^W \vec p_{F_1}^W}{dt},$$
$$\vec v_{F_2}^W = \frac{d^W \vec p_{F_2}^W}{dt},$$
$$\vec v_{F_2}^{F_1} = \frac{d^{F_1}\vec p_{F_2}^{F_1}}{dt}.$$

But $\vec p_{F_2}^{F_1}=\vec p_{F_2}^W-\vec p_{F_1}^W$, so using equation $(1)$ we get:

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]{\vec v_{F_2}^{F_1} = \vec v_{F_2}^W-\vec v_{F_1}^W -\vec\omega_{F_1}^W\!\times\!(\vec p_{F_2}^W-\vec p_{F_1}^W)}$$

Comment: Let us imagine the following:The origin of  $F_1$ coincides with $W$ but is flipped upside down (z-Axis of $F_1$ points along -z-Axis of $W$). Let furthermore $\omega^W_{F_1} = 0$. According to your definition  $\omega^{F_1}_{F_2}$ would be the same as the rotation of $F_2$ measured with respect to the "flipped" transform $W$. This is irritating and appears to be somewhat counterintuitive

Comment: $\omega_{F_1}^W=0$ means that $F_1$ is not rotating with respect to $W$, so the instantaneous rotation of $F_2$ with respect to $W$ equal the instantaneous rotation of $F_2$ with respect to $F_1$ (axes orientation is irrelevant). This result is in fact VERY intuitive, The rotation of $F_1$ from $W$ times the rotation of $F_2$ from $F_1$ is the rotation of $F_2$ from $W$. For infinitesimal rates of rotations this translates into the sum of the angular velocities: $\omega_{F_1}^W+\omega_{F_2}^{F_1} = \omega_{F_2}^{F_1}$, from which my original equation follows.

Comment: Keep in mind that $\omega$ measures the instantaneous rate of rotation, a constant rotation does not affect it, which is why axes orientation does not matter. If $F_1$ is a CONSTANT rotation of $W$, then any other reference  frame will have the same $\omega$ for both. The same thing happens if you change the origin of coordinates.